# change value of input with inline function

Tags: javascript, callback

i have a input and i want access value of input and change it with inline callback function . because of some reason i can not select input with id or class or anything else and i have to use the callback function
my input :

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'input_name' onkeyup = 'my_func()' />
```

with this i can access the value and send it to my_func but i can not change it

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'input_name' onkeyup = 'my_func(this.value)' />


function my_func(value){
 alert(value);
 }
```

in above function when user type something i want change the value of input.
how can i change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

`value = The input's current value`

```
<input type = 'text' name = 'input_name' onkeyup = 'my_func(this)' />


function my_func(input){
   input.value = "hello!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either write your javascript directly into the `onkeyup` event like so:

```html
<input type = 'text' name = 'input_name' onkeyup = 'this.value="custom text"' />
```

Or, you can pass `this` through into your function, and then modify the `.value` property within your function:

```js
function my_func(elem) {
  elem.value = "custom text";
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='input_name' onkeyup='my_func(this)' />
```

**Note**: At the moment your event is only firing when you let go of the key. Consider using `oninput` event instead of `onkeyup` event:

```js
function my_func(elem) {
  elem.value = "custom text";
}
```

```html
<input type='text' name='input_name' oninput='my_func(this)' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element in the function and change the value in the function

```js
function my_func(e){
e.value="hey!"
 alert(e.value);
 }
```

```html
<input type = 'text' name = 'input_name' onkeyup = 'my_func(this)' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your input an id attribute and access it using document.getElementById method. Using this you then change value of the input.

Something like

document.getElementById(‘inputID’).value = ‘hello’;